# Вызов метода с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

Каким способом с помощью рефлексии можно вызвать метод по его названию из определенной области классов? 
Или из любого класса наследника базового класса?

Если вызывать метод с помощью конструкции `this.GetClass().getDeclaredMethod().Invoke()`, то поиск ведется только в этом классе, а не как написано в некоторых туториалах — в классах потомках.

Comment: К сожалению, я не понял, что Вы имеете ввиду. Можете привести пример метода, класса(-ов) и ожидаемого результата вызова?

Answer (score 2):

Для вызова статических методов в классах родителях можете использовать следующий код:

```
public static <T> void invoke(Class<T> type, Class<? super T> parent, String methodName) throws Exception {
    Class<?> currentType = type;

    while (currentType != Object.class) {
        Method method = currentType.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        if (method != null && method.getDeclaringClass() == parent) {
            method.invoke(null);
            return;
        }
        currentType = currentType.getSuperclass();
    }
}
```

Но это работает только **для статических методов**, т.к. в `reflection` нет способа для обхода полиморфизма. Т.е. **нельзя** вызвать определенный метод в классе родителе, если он был переопределен в классе потомке.

Если же вы хотите вызвать методы в классах потомках, то здесь аналогичный подход. Нужно получить все классы загруженные определенным `ClassLoader'ом`, после чего их отфильтровать и вызвать то что нужно.